# PHP mysqli_query not showing up in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to input data into a database with PHP and mysqli. There is no error and the code runs, but when I look in the database, it says that a row has been added but the columns "usernames" and "passwords" are empty.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (usernames, passwords) VALUES ('$username','$password')";
if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    echo "new user successfully created";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
}
```

I think there is something wrong above but I am not sure what it is.

EDIT: I think the problem is with `$username` and `$password` not having any value. It might have to do with the following code:

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { //remove whitespace, slashes, and unnecessary characters
    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
}

function test_input($data) { //function to remove unnecessary characters
    if($data != trim($data)) {
        die("error: there is an unnacceptable character in your username or password");
    }
    if($data != stripslashes($data)) {
        die("error: you cannot have slashes");
    }
    if($data != htmlspecialchars($data)) {
        die("error: password not accepted");
    }
}
```

Comment: check for the `$username` and `$password` values before insert query

Comment: basic debugging `echo $sql;`

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and use a conditional `!empty()` on wherever those variables are assigned as. Sure hope you're hashing this password, one that's of "this century".

Comment: $username and $password probably hold null. Dump their values before the query.
var_dump($username); 
and the same with password. 

This is just to debug for now, in a production environment you should validate your input.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Use prepared statements because those variables shouldn't be trusted. Also, using a $table variable is ripe for problems.. Your code looks like it came straight out of 2001, time to upgrade your PHP toolbox.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am new to PHP and I am just trying to understand the basics for now. If i ever have a real life situation I will be sure to hash the passwords!

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and don't even begin by making crappy applications with PHP http://webdeveloper.gdemolished.com/stop-building-shitty-php-web-applications/

Comment: there isn't enough to go on here. where those variables are coming from, if the columns are long enough to accomodate the data, types etc. only you know that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that was an easy one bro, you slipping ;-)

Comment: @halfstop thank you for this link. You are so right.

Comment: @Dagon *See me roll down the hill.......... from point A to point B*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test_input has no return, its a black hole

```
return $data;
```

at the end is required

Comment: Thank you! this fixed the problem

Comment: now fix the sql injection vulnerability, etc etc etc ;-)

Comment: [*A better "Black hole"...*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mbBbFH9fAg) just don't look at it for too long.